# Periodically running a Jupyter Notebook which contais a git clone command using Github Actions

Tags: python, git, github, jupyter-notebook, github-actions

I have a Jupyter Notebook that first runs a git clone of a repository to obtain the code that is going to run, im trying to periodically run this notebook using Github Actions and for that i do the following:

- Download the Jupyter Notebook and upload it to the repository in which i store the code it runs.
- Have a workflow with the following
  [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS15H.png)

The workflow fails at the "Commit and Push Changes" step with the following error:

error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'myrepository'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

If instead of doing git add --all i add the individual files that i want to upload like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKYWG.png) i get this instead:
fatal: pathspec 'ScrappedData.csv' did not match any files
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'myrepository'

Does anyone know how can i fix either of this problems so i can upload the files?

Comment: Why do you believe your GitHub action runs with the current branch being `master`? See the Usage information [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout/tree/v2.4.1). I'm no GitHub-Actions guru, but you definitely need to decide whether you want a `ref:` and what to do if you need to create a new branch.

Comment: I was following this tutorial @torek https://towardsdatascience.com/scheduling-notebook-and-script-runs-with-github-actions-cc60f3ac17f2

Comment: Ah. That's probably just a bug in the tutorial. In particular, if your branch isn't named `master`, it, well, won't be named `master`.